# How to mock unit functions using Jest in react

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I have below code in my render method

```
render() {
let isNew = Boolean(domService.getQueryParamByName("isNew"));
if(isNew) {
return(
// soemthing
)} else {
return(// return anything)
```

Now how to mock the getQueryParamByName unit function in the jestUnit testcase such that it should cover if block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are importing the domService from another file to your component, inside the test you can add a spy like this:

```
//component.test.js
import domService from "relative-path";

const mockFunction = jest.fn((obj) => {});

beforeEach(() => {
    mockFunction.mockClear();
    jest.spyOn(domService,"getQueryParamByName").mockReturnValue(mockFunction);
});
```